# How to point Azure Function publish to custom python registry?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

How do I point the Azure Function publish function of `Azure Function Core Tools` to a custom registry such as an enterprise [ArtiFactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) instance?

Example:

- When running `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>`, how do I get `requirements.txt` to install from a registry I choose rather than `pypi`?
- Very similar to changing `npm`'s default registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command runs `pip install`, so any [environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables) `pip` looks for will work.

- If you need all your modules from the custom registry, set `PIP_INDEX_URL`
- If you need just some of your modules, then set `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL`

Note that the `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` command performs a Remote Build by default. So, you would have to set the required environment variable as an app setting.

Optionally, you could perform a local build by running `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName> --build local`.

Also, you could also set the same configuration in pip's [config file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) for local builds.

Comment: How can I set that environment variable as an app setting?